# angular2 d3.event.sourceEvent does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, angular

trying to do drag function using d3 on angular2 I found a sample but in JS and trying to use it in ng2 however I have a problem with .sourceEvent it says its not part of the d3.event property.

js type :  https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

```js
public canvas = d3.select('my-app')
        .append('canvas')
        .attr('width', this.width)
        .attr('height', this.height)
        .attr('class', 'canvas');

    public drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("drag", this.dragstart);
    
    dragstart (d) {
       d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `d3.event.stopPropagation()` instead.

And predicting your next error... `d3.select(this)` won't work in Angular2 because the `this` keyword is related to an Angular component. Use `d3.select(d3.event.target)`.